# Is there a way to track all URLs that Jenkins visits during a job completion?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python project running in Jenkins, and I need to track all the URLs that a job in Jenkins visits while executing. Is there a way to get this information?

I have check the logs, but since the project is pretty big and there is not enough documentation, this is pretty hard to track from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about turning off web access for the Jenkins server and see what fails.
Depending on how your Jenkins server is configured, it might be enough to disable Proxy usage. The advantage of this approach is that you are sure you have covered them all.
Perhaps you can provide more details how exactly your project accesses web pages?
Certain tools allow for specific settings or configurations, that's why it would be good to know more details about the case.